# why variable have to be initialized?

Tags: java, switch-statement

here i tried to get output month by inputting month number but why i am having error 
 - "monthString" mightn't have been initialized ? 
 - and why i am not getting output string  from " monthString "?

## why monthString have to be initialized ?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SwitchClass {

public static void main(String[]args)
{
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.printf(" when did u born ? ");
   int monthNumber = input.nextInt();
   String monthString ;

switch (monthNumber)
{
    case 1:
    monthString = "January ";
        break;
    case 2:
        monthString = "February ";
        break;
    case 3:
        monthString = "March ";
        break;
    case 4:
        monthString = "April ";
        break;
    case  5:
        monthString = "May";
        break;
    case  6:
        monthString = "June";
        break;
    case  7:
        monthString = "July";
        break;
    case  8:
        monthString = "August";
        break;
    case  9:
        monthString = "September";
        break;
    case  10:
        monthString = "October";
        break;
    case  11:
        monthString = "November";
        break;
    case  12:
        monthString = "December";
        break;
   }
System.out.println(monthString);       }

 }
```

Answer (score 8):

What if `monthNumber` is not between 1 and 12? In that case, `monthString` won't be initialized. You should give it some default value when you declare it :

```
String monthString = null; // or ""
```

Comment: Or create a default switch case, which gives it a value.

Answer (score 5):

It would be a good idea to add a default case to your switch statement.

Example:

```
switch (monthNumber) {
    case 1: monthString = "January";
        break;

    //other cases...

    default: monthString = "Invalid Month Number";
        break;
}
```

This way if `monthNumber` is not 1-12 then there is still a default case for the switch statement to flow to.

Answer (score 0):

monthString is a local variable within main(), therefore, it must be initialized to prevent the compiler error.

If monthString were a Class variable then it does not have to be initialized explicitly.

You can do this by moving monthString outside of main() and declare it as:

static String monthString;

Answer (score 0):

Because the designer of Java language believes it made more sense for it to be! Codes are easier to read when variables are initialised. A statement `String foo;` feels non-deterministic because you have to guess what's the default value of String is whereas `String foo = null;` is more deterministic.

To give you a more obvious example, consider this:

```
int x;
Int y;
```

Can you very quickly guess what the default values are? You probably have to pause for a few second to realize x is probably 0 and y is probably null

Answer (score -3):

Local variables MUST always be initialized before use.
For Java 6, the compiler doesn't consider the **"Incomplete"** initialization of variables within  flow control blocks and try-catch blocks. The initialization must be done for all cases:

**If - else**:

```
String s;
int a = 10;
if(a > 5){
 s = "5";
}else{
 System.out.println("");
}    
System.out.println(s); // error if s isn't initialized within both if and else blocks
```

**While loop**:

```
String s;
int a = 10;
while(a > 0) {
  s= ">0";
  a--;
}    
System.out.println(s);// error if s isn't initialized outside the while
```

**Try-Catch block**:

```
String s;
try {
 s = "";
    } catch (Exception e) {}
System.out.println(s);// error if s isn't initialized within both try and catch blocks
```

**Switch block**:

```
String s;
int a = 10;
switch (a) {
     case 10: 
         s="10";
         break;
     default:
         break;
         }
System.out.println(s);// error if s isn't initialized all cases, default case included
```

Initialize the variable before the switch and all will be fine.

```
String monthString = "";
```

Comment: @ScottM. I think that my idea is clear now after improving my post.